# insert record in xml file in object oriented way by Linq to xml in c# ? is possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

I have XML file template as :

```
<Students>
    <Student>
        <StudentID></StudentID>
        <Name></Name>
        <Address></Address>
        <EmailId></EmailId>
        <StudentMobile></StudentMobile>
        <ParentName></ParentName>
        <ParentMobile></ParentMobile>
        <Physics></Physics>
        <Chemistry></Chemistry>
        <Mathematics></Mathematics>
        <Biology></Biology>
        <RegistrationDate></RegistrationDate>

    </Student>  
</Students>
```

in my asp.net application. I want to insert the student registration entry through my web form. but want to use proper object oriented method. like by create the object as "Student" it will have required property. and want to insert new node with incremental (auto increment) Student ID. I am using c#. how can i achieve this ? will Linq is best way to do this ?
Please guide me. i am new in XML.

Comment: Some of what you are talking about (auto increment) I associate with database technology.  You didn't mention databases directly in your question, though.

Comment: yes, I want to autoincrement student id (in xml) whenever add new record / node to xml itself. in fact i want to use this xml as database. so sub question may be : can we auto increment id field or need to do it manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got all above asked by :

```
  public void InserStudentByXML(string uri,Student objStudent)
        {
            XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(uri);
            XElement XParentElement = new XElement("Students");
            int studentId = 0;
            studentId = xmlDoc.Descendants("Student").Max(id => (int)id.Attribute("StudentId"));
            studentId += 1;
            objStudent.StudentId = studentId;         
            xmlDoc.Element("Students").Add(
                new XElement("Student",
                                        new XElement("Name", objStudent.StudeentName),
                                        new XElement("Address", objStudent.Address),
                                        new XElement("StudentMobile", objStudent.StudentMobile),
                                        new XElement("EmailId", objStudent.StudentEmailId),
                                        new XElement("ParentName", objStudent.ParentName),
                                        new XElement("ParentMobile", objStudent.ParentMobile),
                                        new XElement("Physics", objStudent.Physics),
                                        new XElement("Chemistry", objStudent.Chemistry),
                                        new XElement("Mathemeatics", objStudent.Mathemeatics),
                                        new XElement("Biology", objStudent.Biology),
                                        new XElement("RegistrationDate", objStudent.RegistrationDate),
                                        new XAttribute("StudentId", objStudent.StudentId)

                                ));
            xmlDoc.Save(uri); 
        }
```

Comment: But still i just want to ask is this safe ?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use object oriented technique then you can use xml serilization and do this work. Where you have to make class accordinto xml schema and will serilize it in xml file. 
you can also use linq. it gives a lot of built in function to do this.

Comment: well fine. by http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/XmlToClassAndBack.aspx article i am able to create the scenario i means able to generate object of my xml file. now please guide me how can i insert this object with values in to xml file ? i mean create new student node by using this generated object? can use LINQ to xml here?